# How do I refer to the grouping of my enums? Basic chess game, wanting to refer to all black/white pieces efficiently

Tags: java, enums

So I have represented different chess pieces as a set of enum called `Chessmen`. (It is a requirement that I set them out like this). I thought it would be a good idea to group these `Chessmen` into a `WHITE` group and a `BLACK` group so for certain situations, I can refer to all white chess pieces or all black pieces.

```
public enum Chessmen {


    WHITE_KING (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_QUEEN (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_ROOK (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_BISHOP (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_KNIGHT (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_PAWN (Group.WHITE),
    BLACK_KING (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_QUEEN (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_ROOK (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_BISHOP (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_KNIGHT (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_PAWN (Group.BLACK),
    EMPTY (Group.NEUTRAL);

    private Group group;

    Chessmen(Group group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public enum Group {
        WHITE,
        BLACK,
        NEUTRAL;
    }
}
```

So for example in the code below I wouldn't have to refer to all of the individual black pieces or white pieces like I have done below (this code 100% works as intended):

```
if (isWhiteMove){
        //Moving the wrong colour piece
        if ((chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == Chessmen.BLACK_KING) || (chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == Chessmen.BLACK_ROOK) ||
                (chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == Chessmen.BLACK_BISHOP) || (chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == Chessmen.BLACK_QUEEN) || 
                (chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == Chessmen.BLACK_KNIGHT) || (chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN)){
            //System.out.println("It is white's move, not black's.");
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            LOGGER.severe("It is white's move, not black's.");
            invalidCounter++;
        }

        //Moving onto one of your own pieces
        if ((chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == Chessmen.WHITE_KING) || (chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == Chessmen.WHITE_ROOK) ||
        (chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == Chessmen.WHITE_BISHOP) || (chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == Chessmen.WHITE_QUEEN) || 
        (chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == Chessmen.WHITE_KNIGHT) || (chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN)){
            //System.out.println("You cannot land on one of your own pieces.");
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            LOGGER.severe("You cannot land on one of your own pieces.");
            invalidCounter++;
        }
    }
```

I have tried a few suggestions based on my own searches, but I can't quite get it right. You can see the `if` statement is quite laborious to look at and to maintain. So below is an example of how I would like my code to look like, but as mentioned, not quite sure how to properly implement it:

```
if (isWhiteMove){
        //Moving the wrong colour piece
        if ((chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY] == **ALL BLACK PIECES IN MY GROUP**){
            //System.out.println("It is white's move, not black's.");
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            LOGGER.severe("It is white's move, not black's.");
            invalidCounter++;
        }

        //Moving onto one of your own pieces
        if ((chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY] == **ALL WHITE PIECES IN MY GROUP**)){
            //System.out.println("You cannot land on one of your own pieces.");
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            LOGGER.severe("You cannot land on one of your own pieces.");
            invalidCounter++;
        }
    }
```

Any help really appreciated thank you. If any more context is needed, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY]` to be equal to all the black pieces. That not possible. A single piece can't be equal to several pieces. You want it to be part of the BLACK (or WHITE) group. I.e. you want its `group` field to be equal to BLACK (or WHITE).

So you just want

```
if (chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY].getGroup() == Chessmen.Group.BLACK)
```

Of course you'll need to add the getGroup() method to Chessmen, otherwise there is no way to know its group from outside of the enum, making the `group` field useless.

Comment: Perfect. This explanation was exactly what I was missing. I didn't think about the need for the `getGroup()`  method. Thanks for helping me to understand. I am going to leave my updated answer on here as a reminder for myself and maybe others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JB Nizet for the comment. A getGroup() method and subsequently, referring to my getGroup() method was all that was required.

```
public enum Chessmen {

    WHITE_KING (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_QUEEN (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_ROOK (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_BISHOP (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_KNIGHT (Group.WHITE),
    WHITE_PAWN (Group.WHITE),
    BLACK_KING (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_QUEEN (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_ROOK (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_BISHOP (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_KNIGHT (Group.BLACK),
    BLACK_PAWN (Group.BLACK),
    EMPTY (Group.NEUTRAL);

    private Group group;

    Chessmen(Group group){
        this.group = group;
    }


    //I needed a getGroup() method here
    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }



    public enum Group {
        WHITE,
        BLACK,
        NEUTRAL;
    }
}
```

Then for my `if` statement, I can use the getGroup() method to access the group I made, which I could not access before.

```
if (isWhiteMove){
        //Moving the wrong colour piece
        if ((chessboard[preMoveX][preMoveY].getGroup() == Chessmen.Group.BLACK)){
            //System.out.println("It is white's move, not black's.");
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            LOGGER.severe("It is white's move, not black's.");
            invalidCounter++;
        }

        //Moving onto one of your own pieces
        if ((chessboard[postMoveX][postMoveY].getGroup() == Chessmen.Group.WHITE)){
            //System.out.println("You cannot land on one of your own pieces.");
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            LOGGER.severe("You cannot land on one of your own pieces.");
            invalidCounter++;
        }
    }
```